# Move Camera in UnityScript 2d in C#

Tags: c#, 2d, unityscript

I have just started programming Unity 2d, and I have faced one large problem: How do I move the camera?  The script is attached to the object "player".  I want it to move with the player.  Thanks!

```
/*
I 
*/
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
 public float speed = 10; //Float for speed
 public string hAxis = "Horizontal";
 void Start ()
 {
     //empty
 }

 void FixedUpdate ()
 {
         if (Input.GetAxis (hAxis) < 0) //Left
         {

                 Vector3 newScale = transform.localScale;
                 newScale.y = 1.0f;
                 newScale.x = 1.0f;
                 transform.localScale = newScale;
         } 
         else if (Input.GetAxis (hAxis) > 0) //Right
         {
                 Vector3 newScale =transform.localScale;
                 newScale.x = 1.0f;
                 transform.localScale = newScale;        
         }
        //Position transformation
    transform.position = transform.position + transform.right * Input.GetAxis(axisName) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any scripts, you could just drag the Camera GameObject to be a child of the player and the camera would start following the player position.

For a script, try this, set player as the target.

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class SmoothCamera2D : MonoBehaviour {

     public float dampTime = 0.15f;
     private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
     public Transform target;

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () 
     {
         if (target)
         {
             Vector3 point = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(target.position);
             Vector3 delta = target.position - camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, point.z)); //(new Vector3(0.5, 0.5, point.z));
             Vector3 destination = transform.position + delta;
             transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, destination, ref velocity, dampTime);
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: But is I attach main camera to object, screen is blue!

Comment: Check transform of the camera as a child of the player, make sure values for x and y are 0 (same position as player) and z is negative (behind player).

Comment: Look in Camera component, check for Size property, change that value